# change button class on event in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am designing MCQ test , I want to show selected button option style to green on click of it.
I have ready code in angular 1 , but not able to convert it into angular 4 .
Code from Angular 1 -

```
<div class="row">
                                <table>
                                    <tr ng-repeat="option in question_option.options" class="mtq_clickable col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                        <td class="mtq_letter_button_td">
                                            <div ng-class="{mtq_css_letter_selected : option.id == question_option.selectedAns}" ng-click="clicked($index+1)" class="mtq_css_letter_button" alt="Question 1, Choice 1">{{option.character}}</div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="mtq_answer_td"><label class="divlabel">{{option.text}}</label></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                    </div>
```

[image]

Code in Angular 4

```
  <table>
                            <tr *ngFor="let options of currentquiz.options" class="mtq_clickable col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <td class="mtq_letter_button_td">

                                    <div [ngClass]="{'mtq_css_letter_button': !clicked, 'mtq_css_letter_selected': clicked}" (click)="clicked = true" alt="Question 1, Choice 1">{{options.renderingtext}}</div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="mtq_answer_td">{{options.text}}</td>
                            </tr>
```

Same i want to achieve through angular 4. Please give some ideas. Currently when i click on one button all option style changes to green.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in angular 1 you are currently saving the id of the option you've clicked and in Angular 4 you are changing a common variable that all buttons are sharing.

Why do not do the same that you're doing in angularjs? This is a super fast approach using a ternary operator in ng-class

```
 <tr *ngFor="let options of currentquiz.options" class="mtq_clickable col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <td class="mtq_letter_button_td">
       <div [ngClass]="{clicked(option.id) ? 'mtq_css_letter_selected': 'mtq_css_letter_button'}" (click)="click(option.id)" alt="Question 1, Choice 1">{{options.renderingtext}}</div>
    </td>
    <td class="mtq_answer_td">{{options.text}}</td>
 </tr>
```

And in your component.ts

```
public clickedId : number;

click(id: number) {
    this.clickedId = id;
}

clicked(id: number): boolean {
   return this.clickedId === id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your options class/interface, add a variable clicked. Then change the html like this:

> ```
> <table>
>     <tr *ngFor="let options of currentquiz.options"
>     class="mtq_clickable col-md-6 col-sm-6">
>         <td class="mtq_letter_button_td">
>             <div [ngClass]="{'mtq_css_letter_button': !options.clicked, 'mtq_css_letter_selected': options.clicked}"
>             (click)="options.clicked = true"
>             alt="Question 1, Choice 1">{{options.renderingtext}}</div>
>         </td>
>         <td class="mtq_answer_td">{{options.text}}</td>
>     </tr>
> </table>
> ```

Comment: It can select all options one by one  i want to select only 1

Comment: You need to have inputs. Here is a link which will help you: https://jsfiddle.net/KTADZ/